# How to fire javascript method after a page has rendered

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Hi guys I need to call a javascript function after the page is rendered.

How can I do this?

I tried the  `public void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)` event.

But my javascript failed because the controls were not rendered yet.

Answer (score 2):

**Pure javascript:**

```
<body onLoad="foo()">
```

or

```
window.onload = foo;
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(foo); // DOM ready
```

or

```
$(window).load(foo); // onLoad (DOM + images)
```

Answer (score 0):

Cant you call the method in the window.onload event?

```
window.onload = function() {  
  init();  
  doSomethingElse();  
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `window.onload` event

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At
>   this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all
>   the images and sub-frames have finished loading.

Example :

```
function load() {  
    alert("load event detected!");  
}  
window.onload = load;
```

Explanation here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload

Answer (score 0):

in JQuery we usually do this:

```
$(function() {

 // put your code here

});
```

see here: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

any objections in using jQuery? There you can find a document.ready() function that executes when the document is loaded (since that differs in browsers as well).